# How to open a UIWebview and play video fullscreen and force landscape?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to launch a webview that will play a youtube video full screen and landscape.
Most of the other posts on this are buggy and clunky, is there a simple and clean way I can implement this or do I have to use something like MPMoviePlayerController to get this effect?

Thanks!

Comment: You can not play YouTube videos within MPMoviePlayerController directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to display videos in *UIWebViews* are HTML5 *video* tags. [YouTube uses iframes](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html) to embed their HTML5 videos:

```
<iframe 
  class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" 
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

I don't have real experience in the forced orientation issue, so I skip this part.

Comment: Yeah looks like this is the best solution after some research.